# Простуда на губах. Кавычки

Tags: кавычки

Простуда на губах. Имеется в виду вирус герпеса. Стоит ли писать простуду в кавычках?

Answer (score 3):

Употребеление кавычек зависит **от стиля речи**. В специализированной речи (мелицинских справочниках, статьях на медицинские темы) кавычки ставятся, так как  слово разговорного,  а не научного  стиля.

Но в общеупотребительной речи и художественных текстах ставить кавычки не надо, так как это значение, а также **примеры** употребления словосочетания указаны **в словаре,** и там кавычек нет.

Также кавычки могут ставиться, если вы  **даете определение** заболеванию: поражение на губах обычно называется «простудой».

**ПРОСТУДА,** -ы; ж. 1. Болезнь, вызванная переохлаждением организма; переохлаждение организма, вызывающее такую болезнь. Сильнейшая п. у кого-л. Получить п. Бояться простуды. 2. **Небольшое болезненное вздутие** (обычно на губе, в носу), вызванное переохлаждением; герпес. **П. выскочила. У меня на губе п.** <Простудный, -ая, -ое. П-ое заболевание. Симптомы простудного характера. П. кашель (вызванный простудой). П-ая погода (способная вызвать простуду). Простудно, нареч. П. кашлять, сипеть.

Comment: Как это "что за словарь"? Самый правильный словарь Кузнецова,  так как нам его Грамота предлагает. Все претензии, пожалуйста, туда.

Comment: Это с вашим ответом что-то не так, с ним разбирайтесь. Вот обычное предложение на эту тему: Противовирусная и антибактериальная мазь от простуды на губах (герпеса) – самое распространенное средство лечения этого заболевания. Кавычек нет, как видите. И все виноваты тоже у вас - Кузнецов, Грамота, ну и я, конечно, за компанию. И додумывать причины, по которой Грамота размещает на своем сайте учебные материалы, тоже не надо

Answer (score 1):

Герпес не является простудой. Это т.н. "народное" название [аналогично английскому "cold sores" (букв. "простудные язвы"), французскому "bouton de fièvre" (букв. "температурная болячка"), немецкому "Fieberblasen" (букв. "лихорадковые волдыри")].

В строго-медицинском смысле *простуда* это вирусное (как правило) воспаление верхних дыхательных путей.

С давних пор считалось, что простуда вызывается переохлаждением, но сейчас мы знаем, что это не так (хотя сильное переохлаждение может повысить восприимчивость к вирусу).

Однако, в бытовой среде многих языков сохранилось значение простуды, как болезни, вызванной холодом, а также как самого переохлаждения (гипотермии).

Это значение закреплено и в большинстве толковых словарей:

> ПРОСТУДА Охлаждение, резкая перемена температуры, которой подвергся организм. Болезнь, вызванная простудой.
>
> — Толковый словарь Ушакова<sup>1</sup>

> ПРОСТУДА Болезнь, вызванная охлаждением организма; само такое охлаждение.
>
> — Толковый словарь Ожегова<sup>2</sup>

> ПРОСТУДА Болезнь, вызванная охлаждением организма человека.
>
> — Толковый словарь Ефремовой<sup>3</sup>

> ПРОСТУДА Болезнь, от внезапного охлаждения кожи, либо от остановки испарины.
>
> — Толковый словарь Даля (современная орфография) <sup>4</sup>

В [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3#) до второй половины XX в. нет употреблений *простуда на губах*, что наводит на мысль о недавности заимствования.

В самых свежих словарях можно найти упоминание герпеса с пометой о просторечности:

> ПРОСТУДА 1 Легкое заболевание органов дыхания, вызванное переохлаждением и обычно выражающееся в насморке или кашле.
>
> ПРОСТУДА 2 разг. или прост. Небольшие пузырьки в области губ или носа, которые могут появляться при простуде.
>
> — Проспект активного словаря русского языка под редакцией Апресяна (РАН ИРЯ им. Виноградова, 2010)<sup>5</sup>

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>6</sup>:

> §151. Кавычками выделяются иностилевые слова, подчеркивается ироническое значение слова, дается указание на двойной смысл слова или смысл, известный лишь тому,кому адресованы слова.
>
> §152. Кавычками выделяются слова, употребляемые в особом, часто условном значении.

То есть, у слова есть три значения: строго медицинское, бытовое, и просторечное.

И в зависимости от стиля текста и конкретного смысла, варьируется и применение кавычек.

Если вы говорите о медицинском понимании слова *простуда*, то кавычки не требуются:

*Простуда зачастую сопровождается кашлем и насморком.*

Если вы говорите о бытовом понимании слова *простуда*, то кавычки требуются только в контексте медицинской литературы:

*Особо трудна диагностика бронхита из-за его "простудных" симптомов.*

но

*Простудился и лежу с бронхитом в больнице.*

Если вы говорите о герпесных пузырьках, то кавычки требуются вокруг слова "простуда" (но могут быть поставлены и вокруг сочетания "простуда на губах"), кроме случаев передачи устной речи и просторечного стиля:

*Пациент жалуется на "простуду" на верхней губе.*

*Сюрприз был так же неожиданен и неприятен, как "простуда" на губе.*

*— Вася, у тебя что, простуда опять вскочила?*

Из [архивной версии](http://web.archive.org/web/20191018151045/https://www.who.int/ru/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/herpes-simplex-virus) страницы ВОЗ:

> Поражение на губах обычно называется «простудой».

и

> ВПГ-1 передается главным образом через оральный контакт и вызывает оральный герпес (симптомы которого могут проявляться в виде «простуды на губах»), но также может вызвать и генитальный герпес.

---

1. Волин Б. М., Ушаков Д. Н., Виноградов В. В., Винокур Г. О., Ларин Б. А., Ожегов С. И., Томашевский Б. В. Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией проф. Д. Н. Ушакова / Том III П–РЯШКА — М: Государственное издательство иностранных и национальных словарей, 1939.
2. Ожегов С. И., Шведова Н. Ю. Толковый словарь русского языка — М.: Азъ, 1992.
3. Ефремова Т. Ф. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный: В 2 т. — М.: Русский язык, 2000.
4. Толковый словарь живаго великорускаго языка В. И. Даля. — М.: Издание Общ-ва любителей российской словесности, 1863—1866.
5. Проспект активного словаря русского языка / Авторы: В. Ю. Апресян, Ю. Д. Апресян, Е. Э. Бабаева, О. Ю. Богуславская, И. В. Галактионова, М. Я. Гловинская, Б. Л. Иомдин, Т. В. Крылова, И. Б. Левонтина, А. В. Птенцова, А. В. Санников, Е. В. Урысон; Рецензенты: В. З. Демьянков, Л. П. Крысин; Отв. ред. акад. Ю. Д. Апресян. — М.: Языки славянских культур, 2010.
6. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: В ответе дано много познавательных сведений медицинского характера, но сам ответ нельзя считать корректным. Автор предлагает ставить кавычки во всех случаях, а это неверно. Слово "простуда"  всем хорошо известно, условного (переносного) значения в нем тоже нет.  Так что постановка кавычек зависит от стиля речи.

Comment: Чудненько, вы, оказывается, не безнадежны, мне это нравится. Могу добавить следующее. В Нацкорпусе с этим  словом 392 примера, но все перебирать сложно. Там простудой называют в основном наше ОРЗ, связанное с переохлаждением, но слово очень давнее, тогда оно не было еще только бытовым и просторечным. Например: «Во всю ту осень по Москве свирепствовала какая-то эпидемическая простуда, называемая grippe. [И. М. Долгоруков. Часть 4 / 1799-1806 (1788-1822)].

Comment: А это данные по словарю Кузнецова. Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года.

Comment: И вот что еще могу добавить. Вы ведь хотите, чтобы ваши ответы выглядели идеально? Согласно современному информационному принципу, идеальный ответ начинается с ответа, то есть с вывода. Эту часть  прочитает  автор вопроса, которого интересует только сам ответ: как писать. Вторая часть посвящается обоснованию: почему так надо писать. Здесь лучше выглядит короткий пересказ или цитирование правила в той части, которая непосредственно касается данной темы. Ну и  дается ссылка на всё правило.

Comment: А далее при желании можно изложить любые дополнительные сведения, их прочитают самые любопытные. Надеюсь, что эта информация показалась вам полезной. Спасибо за внимание.